# Why after adding login tag in visual studio it is giving error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

---

> How to fix this problem ?... I am not understanding that !... I have given my HTML code and the error pic ! and it is occouring after adding this line  
>   plz help

[image: This is showing after running visual studio]

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Signin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Signin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>ESbook</h1>
        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate">
        </asp:Login>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blWfL.png)

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your codes requires a reference to jQuery libraries.

Before donwloading and referencing the jQuery place this line of code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

agter `<title>`tag in your `<head>` block.